# Rails 4 Permit parameter, by overriding gem class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am facing UnPermitted Parameter issue. Was not able to solve it after multiple attempts. Can anyone point me in right direction.

Am using gem "Surveyor" and gem "SurveyorGui".

In below code i want to add "mission_id" attribute, this class file is present inside gem "surveyor_gui". File Location Path is surveyor_gui/app/models/permitted_params_decorator.rb

```
PermittedParams.class_eval do
  .....

  alias_method :base_survey_attributes, :survey_attributes
  def survey_attributes
    base_survey_attributes +
    [:title, :access_code, :template, :id, :user_id,
      survey_sections_attributes: survey_section_attributes]
  end
 .....      
end
```

Github File link [permitted_params_decorator.rb](https://github.com/kjayma/surveyor_gui/blob/318112a1e80eebd12feff30076481cfe21c839d8/app/models/permitted_params_decorator.rb)

How do i override it, to permit additional parameters in Rails 4. I tried, to create class in folder name "surveyor-gui" too, but it didn't worked.

Any help is highly appreciated
THanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved it.

1. Created a file named "attribute_permitter.rb" in models folder.(you can also place it in libs)

/app/models/surveyor_gui/attribute_permitter.rb"

```
module AttributePermitter
  # survey_attributes base method found in surveyor gem.
  # surveyor_gui gem override's survey_attributes method.
  # We extend method to include our parameters.  
  # More Details http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/04/alternatives-for-redefining-methods.html
  def survey_attributes
    super + [:mission_id]
  end

  def question_attributes
    super
  end

  def question_group_attributes
    super
  end

  def answer_attributes
    super
  end

end
```

2. Specify "attribute_permitter.rb" in config/initializers/extensions.rb.
   (Like below, if extensions.rb is not present, create it to override.)

extensions.rb:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/surveyor_gui/attribute_permitter.rb"
```

3. Use it in your controller like below.

Controller:

```
 private
 def surveyforms_params
  ::PermittedParams.new(params[:surveyform]).extend(AttributePermitter).survey
 end
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

To override a method, make use of module_eval :

1. Ex: To override a method in question_type_methods.rb.
   https://github.com/kjayma/surveyor_gui/blob/33ed11a321e30a411f862ad98d3d78150f93bf47/lib/surveyor_gui/models/question_type_methods.rb

Created file in #{Rails.root}/lib/surveyor_gui/models/question_type_methods.rb

```
SurveyorGui::Models::QuestionTypeMethods.module_eval do


  ...... 
  def _create_an_omit_answer(question, is_exclusive, omit_text)

    if is_exclusive
      display_order = question.answers.size > 0 ? question.answers.last.display_order+1 : 0
      _create_an_answer(display_order, omit_text, question, is_exclusive: is_exclusive)
    end
  end

  .......


end
```

2. Specify it in extensions.rb

extensions.rb

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/surveyor_gui/models/question_type_methods.rb"
```

NOTE: If there is any other elegant solution, pls post as answer :)

Comment: How to extend module of surveyor gui gem? I want to change text of question types.